# Net Cassandra Easy set keyspace

Tags: perl, cassandra

After starting Cassandra server and Cassandra Client, I created 'Keyspace1', column family 'Standard1' successfully. Using Net-Cassandra-Easy-0.15, I executed a Perl program and got result:

```
$VAR1=bless({
    'why'=>'You have not set a keyspace for this session'
    },'Net::GenCassandra::InvalidrequestException');
```

Do you have any hint to solve this problem?

My Perl program is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use lib './lib';
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Cassandra::Easy;
use Data::Dumper;

eval {
    my $client = Net::Cassandra::Easy->new(
    server => 'localhost',
    port => 9160,
    keyspace => 'Keyspace1');
    $client->connect();
    my $key = 'rt';
    # get
    my $result = $client->get([$key],
        family => 'Standard1',
        byname => [qw/name age site/]);
    print Dumper($result);
    # insert
    $client->mutate([$key],
        family => 'Standard1',
        insertions => { 'site' => 'rest-term' });
    # get
    $result = $client->get([$key],
        family => 'Standard1',
        byname => [qw/name age site/]);
    print Dumper($result);
};
die Dumper($@) if $@;
```

Comment: For more information: before this problem happen, I got "Could not read 4 bytes..." error. I replaced "BufferedTransport" by "FramedTransport" in the Easy.pm module then "Could not read 4 bytes..." error was fixed. But this "You have not set a keyspace for this session" error, I haven't known any method to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is see this in CPAN reviews:

"This might be a good module if it were updated, but this version is too old to be useful. It appears this module will not work with any version of Cassandra above 5.x. "

What cassandra version are you using?

There is a test.pl in this package, try to run it.

My guess is that your Keyspace1 is not a valid keyspace in your cassandra install. Are you able to run this query with some commandline tool?

Comment: My problem happened with Cassandra 1.0.7 (latest for now). I haven't known the reason yet. I changed to version 0.7.10 and use Thrift0.7.0 with gen-perl (not use Easy anymore), it's working well now. Thank you!